# RAW files store 3 colors per pixel, or only one?

Tags: raw, sensor, megapixels, bit-depth, bayer

[Ken Rockwell says](http://www.kenrockwell.com/tech/bayer.htm) that camera makers consider the individual R/G/B sensors when they talk about megapixels. So the image below would be a 6x6 pixel camera, not 3x3 as you would imagine.

[image]

If that's true, a RAW file would contain only one color information per pixel (be it R, G or B) as a 10, 12 or 14 bit number.

My confusion comes as I read in some places stuff like:

- RAW files store an avarage of the two green sensors per pixel.
- RAW files use 12 bits per pixel, but there are 3 colors so that's actually 36 bits per pixel.

Which would obviously be false, if Ken's claim is correct.

So what's the truth?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Raw files don't really store *any* colors per pixel. They only store a single brightness value per pixel.

It is true that with a Bayer mask over each pixel the light is filtered with either a Red, Green, or Blue filter¹ over each pixel well. But there's no hard cutoff where *only* green light gets through to a green filtered pixel or *only* red light gets through to a red filtered pixel. There's a lot of overlap. A lot of red light and some blue light gets through the green filter. A lot of green light and even a bit of blue light makes it through the red filter, and some red and green light is recorded by the pixels that are filtered with blue.

[image: color response]

Since a raw file is a set of single luminance values for each pixel on the sensor there is no actual per-pixel color information to a raw file. Color is derived by comparing adjoining pixels that are filtered for one of three colors with a Bayer mask. But just like putting a red filter in front of the lens when shooting black and white film didn't result in a monochromatic red photo (or a B&W photo where *only* red objects have any brightness at all), the Bayer mask in front of monochromatic pixels doesn't create color either. What it does is change the tonal value (how bright or how dark the luminance value of a particular color is recorded) of various colors by differing amounts. When the tonal values (gray intensities) of adjoining pixels filtered with the three different colors used in the Bayer mask are compared then colors may be interpolated from that information. This is the process we refer to as *demosaicing*.

A lot of math is done to assign an R, G, and B value for *each* pixel. There are a lot of different models for doing this interpolation. How much bias is given to red, green, and blue in the demosaicing process is what sets *white/color balance*. The gamma correction and any additional shaping of the light response curves is what sets *contrast*. But in the end an R, G, and B value is assigned to every pixel. **In your 6x6 pixel example in the question the result of demosaicing would be a 36 pixel image with 36 pixels that each have a Red, a Green, and a Blue value.**

A little bit of resolution is lost in translation. It turns out that in terms of the number of alternating black and white lines per inch or mm that can be resolved by a sensor with an RGGB Bayer mask and well-done demosaicing the absolute resolution limit of a Bayer sensor is about 1/√2 compared to a monochromatic sensor that has no Bayer mask and thus needs no demosaicing (but can only see in Black & White).

Even when your camera is set to save raw files, the image you see on the back of the LCD screen of your camera just after you take the picture is *not* the unprocessed raw data. It is a preview image generated by the camera by applying the in camera settings to the raw data that results in the jpeg preview image you view on the LCD. This preview image is appended to the raw file along with the data from the sensor and the EXIF information that contains the in-camera settings at the time the photo was shot.

The in camera development settings for things like white balance, contrast, shadow, highlights, etc. do not affect the actual data from the sensor that is recorded in a raw file. Rather, all of those settings are listed in another part of the raw file.

When you open a "raw" file on your computer you see one of two different things:

- The preview jpeg image created by the camera at the time you took the photo. The camera used the settings in effect when you took the picture and appended it to the raw data in the .cr2 file. If you're looking at the image on the back of the camera, it is the jpeg preview you are seeing.
- A conversion of the raw data by the application you used to open the "raw" file. When you open a 12-bit or 14-bit 'raw' file in your photo application on the computer, what you see on the screen is an 8-bit rendering of the demosaiced raw file that is a lot like a jpeg, not the actual monochromatic Bayer-filtered 14-bit file. As you change the settings and sliders the 'raw' data is remapped and rendered again in 8 bits per color channel.

Which you see will depend on the settings you have selected for the application with which you open the raw file.

If you are saving your pictures in raw format when you take them, when you do post processing you'll have the exact same information to work with no matter what development settings were selected in camera at the time you shoot. Some applications *may* initially open the file using either the jpeg preview or by applying the in-camera settings active at the time the image was shot to the raw data but you are free to change those settings, without any destructive data loss, to whatever else you want in post.

Canon's *Digital Photo Professional* will open a .cr2 raw file in the same *Picture Style* as was selected in camera when shot. All you have to do to change it is use the drop-down menu and select another *Picture Style*. You can even create a "recipe" for one image and then batch apply it to all of the images before beginning to work with them. Other manufacturer's raw processing software is similar and there's usually an option to have the application open an image with the in camera development settings applied.

With third party raw processing applications such as Adobe's *Lightroom* or *Camera Raw*, Apple's *Aperture* or *Photos*, PhaseOne's *Capture One Pro*, DxO Lab's *OpticsPro*, etc. getting images to display according to the in camera settings can be a bit trickier. Adobe products, for instance, ignore most all of the *maker notes* section of a raw file's EXIF data where many manufacturers include at least some of the information about in camera settings.

<sub>¹ The actual colors of the Bayer mask in front of the sensors of most color digital cameras are: Blue - a slightly violet version of blue centered at 450 nanometers, Green - a slightly yellowish version of green centered on about 540 nanometers, and Red - a slightly orange version of yellow. What we call "red" is the color we perceive for light at about 640 nanometers in wavelength. The "red" filters on most Bayer arrays allow the most light through at somewhere around 590-600 nanometers. [The overlap between the "green" and "red" cones in the human retina](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/99711/15871) are even closer than that, with "red" centered at about 565 nanometers, which is what we perceive as yellow-green.</sub>

Comment: This is fundamentally incorrect. You say (or at least very strongly imply) that this works because color information *leaks* into the neighbors. That's not necessary. Raw would work fine if the filters would be absolutely perfect. Different demosaicing algorithms "involve a lot of math", but the simplest one is to just *average the nearby pixels* and this works surprisingly well. I guess done several million times in a multi-megapixel image that's technically "a lot" of math, but it's not complicated math — it's third-grade-level stuff.

Comment: Bayer works because it's generally a good *guess* that the pixel at for example a blue-filtered location has the same amount of green as the green pixels next to it (and the same for red). When this guess is off, you get artifacts, and that's what the more complicated algorithms attempt to resolve. They don't work by assuming special knowledge about the frequency response of the filters.

Comment: "You say (or at least very strongly imply) that this works because color information leaks into the neighbors." **I say nor imply nothing of the sort.** I only state the fact that filters *aren't* absolutely perfect and thus the idea that each set of filtered pixels is an accurate representation of that color, as is often presented by those such as Ken Rockwell (mentioned in the question), is utterly ridiculous.

Comment: I may have been misunderstanding what you've been saying all along then, since you do bring this up often. :) Especially since you open the answer with it, could you maybe edit to explain in a way that makes that more clear? Particularly, do you mean that the overlapping filters mean the result is fundamentally inaccurate no matter what processing is done and we just live with that, or that it can be made accurate by some transform in demosiacing, or that it can be made more accurate by another step that rendering RAW files requires (but which is not part of demosiacing)?

Comment: I only mean that too many people describe the Bayer mask incorrectly as *only* allowing green light through the green filter, *only* allowing red light through the red filter, and *only* allowing blue light through the blue filter. That's no more the case than saying that by using a green filter with B&W film would only allow the green light in the scene to be captured. Using a green filter only means that green light is allowed through at a higher transmissive rate than red or blue light is, but some of all three gets through. It's only by comparing the differences between the light...

Comment: ...filtered by all three colors can we truly approximate any of the colors for any of the pixels. As you yourself said in [an answer](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/81977/15871), "'Color' as we understand it isn't a real property of anything in the universe."

Comment: @mattdm averaging the nearby pixels produces a very blurry photo, and there's no camera on the market that does it that way. Demosaicing algorithms take advantage of the correlation between the RGB pixels to greatly improve resolution, at the cost of the occasional artifact. And there's definitely heavy math involved.

Comment: @MarkRansom Of course — the basic algorithm isn't the best. *But it is just fine for reconstructing perfectly decent color.* Nothing more sophisticated than is required for that. See [this answer for practical examples](http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/22609/1943) if you don't believe me.

Comment: "A lot of math..." doesn't necessarily require that it be highly complex math. A lot of simple arithmetic is still "...a lot of math." A raw file with 20 million pixels requires millions of arithmetic operations to demosaic it. If you don't think that is a lot of math, try doing it by hand!

Comment: @MichaelClark I dare you to come up with e.g. a simple bicubic filter without an extensive math background. The calculations themselves may be simple, but determining the factors that go into those calculations is anything but.

Comment: @mattdm I didn't mean to imply that simple algorithms couldn't produce perfectly recognizable results, just that they're not adequate for our pixel-peeping ways. Only the cheapest video or webcams would try to get away with it.

Comment: @MarkRansom You're reading *way* too much into my previous comment which was a response to Matt's initial comment that seems to imply that averaging nearby pixels doesn't require a lot of math. Please just take it at face value" "A lot of arithmetic is still a lot of math." That statement doesn't exclude the possibility that more complex math is involved in determining what calculations need to be made or even in those calculations themselves.

Comment: @mattdm It is a fundamental misunderstanding that CFA filters would produce better color if they did not overlap each other. In fact good color rendition requires significant spectral overlap without which there is no way the Luther-ives condition can be met, or even closely approximated. This is unrelated to demosaicing since the color, in a CIEXYZ sense, of a large area is purely a function of the 3 "RGB" levels. Good color rendition requires significant overlap.

Comment: @doug Yeah, I get into that in much greater detail in [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/99711/15871) to the more recent question:  *Why are Red, Green, and Blue the primary colors of light?*

Comment: There's also the fact that the colors used in Bayer masks are not the same colors emitted by our RGB screens. "Red" is not even close. The "red" cones in our retinas are most sensitive to about 564nm (a lime-green color between green and yellow), the "red" filters in most Bayer masks are most transmissive to about 590-600nm (orange-yellow), while our RGB systems emit 640-650nm for "red".</sub>

Comment: What is still confusing in the answer (maybe explain it better, or show some graphics) is the fact that four sensor pixels are needed to make one colored pixel, but the example does not have 3x3 color pixels, but 6x6 (demosaicing, as claimed). I don't get it how four different colored pixels are made from the single colored pixel then.

Comment: Four color pixels do not make one color pixel. In most Bayer masked sensors, the output is one color pixel for each photosite/sensel/pixel well on the sensor. The number of sensels used to interpolate the color values for each pixel are usually in the dozens for most demosaicing algorithms, with those further away having less influence than those closer..

Comment: In other words, every color value in a color digital image is purely synthetic. This is by necessity, since every color we "see" is a synthetic perception created by our brain. There's no real thing as "color" in the nature of the electromagnetic spectrum, most of which we do not perceive as "light", much less as "color". There is only the *perception* of color created by our eye-brains systems (or our camera sensor/digital processing systems) in response to certain wavelengths within a very narrow band of the entire electromagnetic spectrum.

Comment: Without overlap between the sensitivities of the photosites filtered with each of the different color filters, our cameras could not produce output that would satisfy the Luther-Ives condition just as without the overlap in the sensitivity of the three types of cones in the human retina our brains could not create a perception of color.

Comment: With raw files there is no such thing as a "red" pixel, or a "green" pixel, or a "blue" pixel. The single brightness value measured by each photosite must be processed using the brightness difference with adjacent and other nearby photosites with a differently colored filter in front of them in order to assign a "red", "green", and "blue" value to the position of each photosite. But "red", "green", and "blue" exist only in the processed image because red, green, and blue are what our display devices use to stimulate our retinal cones to have a similar response as to the original light.

Answer (score 6):

Ken is right in the claim you quote — sort of. It is correct that digital cameras today (with the exception of those with Sigma's Foveon sensors) work by using a Bayer matrix, and sensor resolution is quoted as the size of the matrix. Your example image represents a "36 pixel" sensor. However, it's important to recognize that cameras turn this into a full color image *of the full specified size in actual pixels*, and that **this is not as bad as Ken makes it out to be**.

Several things he says in that article are downright wrong, starting with:

> As of 2006 these clever algorithms allow starting with one-third the data and making it look about as good as having one-half the number of pixels claimed.

This was nonsense in 2006 and is nonsense today. The process works on some simple assumptions. More of which are laid out [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/30952/1943), but the basic one is that you can predict what the "missing" information should be looking at the different-colored neighbor pixels. This turns out to be a good assumption most of the time, and very wrong other times. In cases where there is not a lot of very detailed transition between colors, the result is just as good as if each sensel recorded full color. In cases where the assumption is wrong, it's much worse. In the real world, the former is actually very common and works much better than "one-half" — but the important thing is that it is context-dependent.

> RAW offers no advantages here, except for one potential gamble. Bayer interpolation takes place in the software opening the raw data. Future advances in Bayer interpolation algorithms could be incorporated in future raw software, if and only if your camera maker continues to support yesterday's cameras in tomorrow's software. Just as likely, your camera maker may no longer support your old camera in tomorrow's raw software!

He's right in that shooting RAW does not change the fundamentals, but the idea that old files will stop working is *basically nonsense*. Since old cameras use the same basic principle, and fundamentally similar file formats, it doesn't cost much to bring support for old models along indefinitely, and vendors have plenty of incentive to do so — and even if that would happen, there are great open source decoders.

And of course, keeping RAW files offers [other advantages](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2627/good-examples-of-raws-advantages-over-jpeg) not related to demosaicing.

But it's also silly to say that the possibility of future improvements is the *only* advantage. As I said, there are different assumptions which can be made about the content of your image, and different algorithms (or tweaks to those algorithms) will suit different real-world situations better, so if you find yourself in a situation where you are getting moire or other artifacts, you may be able to deal with that. (Although, I should add that this is at the very fussy level — there's very rarely a situation where peeking this closely is worthwhile.)

There's also a factor which Ken may be excused for because the article is a decade old. In 2006, most cameras were in the 5-8 megapixel range, with high-end DSLR models stretching to 12. Now, typical low/mid-range DSLRs and mirrorless cameras offer 16 and 24 megapixels, and it goes up from there. At this point, quibbling about color detail at the pixel-peeping level is *really* academic, because in the real world it's very rare that lighting, lenses, stability, and everything else line up so well that this is the limiting factor.

In general, a lot of Ken Rockwell's site is like this. (See [this answer for more](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10980/are-equipment-reviews-from-websites-like-kenrockwell-com-and-bythom-com-reliable/11038#11038).) This is unfortunate, as he actually has a lot of interesting things to say and some good advice, but there's a lot of nonsense as well, and rather than admitting that or improving it, he tends to double down, and then claims that the whole site is satire.

Oh, and a bonus fun-fact: camera rear LCD screens and EVFs also use three colored sub-pixels to represent one digital pixel, and these screens are usually marketed with the count of the *sub-pixels* — effectively 3× what you might expect from the way computer screen resolution is given.

Comment: "Just as likely, your camera maker may no longer support your old camera in tomorrow's raw software!" We are left with a few remaining film processing labs. Supply constraints will likely end film processing. Will this happen with RAW files? Literally every file created by a computer since 70's is still usable on any modern software as long as its structure is documented or reverse-engineered.

Answer (score 2):

It is all true, but the interpretation can be stretched.

That specific raw color pattern is called a Bayer pattern.

Yes, raw is one color per pixel, and that one pixel is (typically) 12 bits. So there are three colors of raw pixels, some are blue, some are red, and 2x those counts are green.

Then later, the raw processing software (to make RGB JPG, it could be immediately in the camera, or could be external much later) converts the raw data into a RGB image so we can use it. This is interpolation, neighboring pixels of the other two colors are combined into each of these RGB pixels, but all do become RGB pixels.  At that point, it is 36 bit RGB pixels, however the spatial resolution is slightly compromised, with the various pixel data being shared with neighbors.  We may end up with (for example) 6000 RGB pixels of sensor width, but it came from 2000 blue and 2000 red sensors, etc. (and the data is also shared vertically, it comes from more than three pixels).  This is called demosaicing ... which can be found online.

Comment: IMHO typically are 14 bits. Only old cameras (Canon S120 for example) store 12 bits per pixel

Comment: @RomeoNinov, it's not as simple as old vs new. E.g. some Nikons let you choose 12 bits or 14 bits, so you can make a tradeoff of image depth vs continuous shooting rate and image size.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, never know this, I am Canon shooter. But this should for me like exception, not like rule (12 bits). And as far as I remember some cameras store in 16 bits per pixel

Comment: Would be a much stronger argument if you provided any evidence of most Canon cameras being 14 bits.  **Here is Canon saying otherwise:**  http://cpn.canon-europe.com/content/education/infobank/capturing_the_image/8_or_16_bit.do  **"Most EOS digital cameras capture images in 12-bit mode"**

Comment: @WayneF Based on the camera referenced as Canon's best at the time (1D Mark II), that article was written sometime between April 2004 (when the 1D II replaced the 1D) and June 2005 (when the 1D Mark IIN replaced the 1D II).

Answer (score 0):

Cameras with CFA that are not Sigma Foveon literally have an array of single sensors each having a single capacitor. Naturally, raw file would be something directly read out of this array. It makes no sense to rearrange this information in the raw file because it's purpose is to be fed to an advanced program on a large computer which can make all the transformation on itself.

> RAW files store an avarage of the two green sensors per pixel.

That's a double lie because:

- raw files are not organized with regards to colour
- debayerization does not combine pixels, instead it interpolates the absent colours for each pixel.

> RAW files use 12 bits per pixel, but there are 3 colors so that's actually 36 bits per pixel.

That's a triple lie:

- debayerization does not combine pixels
- even if it would, it would mean 48 bits per RGGB block
- a lot of expensive cameras have 14 bit sensor readout.