# Do different smartphone apps create different raw pictures?

Tags: raw, image-quality, android-app

Androids camera-2 API supports taking photos in raw format (dng for my Nexus 5) with an appropriate camera app.
Since there are different apps I could use, I'm wondering if the raw picture data depends on the app used taking the picture? In other words: is it possible that two different camera apps create different raw pictures when everything else stays the same (motive, lightning, ISO, shutter speed, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that two different camera apps create different raw pictures when everything else stays the same (motive, lightning, ISO, shutter speed, etc)?

The raw data is the same. But raw data isn't directly viewable in the way we normally expect an image to look. It's just a bunch of monochromatic luminance values for each pixel that has been filtered to be most sensitive to one of three colors used in the Bayer mask that the vast majority of digital cameras use. So each application must take the raw data and convert it to a form we can view. Things such as color temperature/white balance, saturation, contrast, brightness, etc. are determined by the way the viewing application interprets the raw data. So different apps can interpret the same data differently.

For more about what raw files contain and what they do not, please see: [RAW files store 3 colors per pixel, or only one?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/86170/raw-files-store-3-colors-per-pixel-or-only-one)

Answer (score 3):

Raw picture is provided by the phone's operating system and should be the same regardless of used application. But raw data format can't be viewed directly and different applications will have different interpretation of the raw data.

Answer (score 0):

According to this article the DNG produced by the Lightroom Mobile app is very different in both size and quality from the one produced by LG G4's native app. Which i found a bit weird, and that's how i ended up here.

http://tristanpaviot.fr/en/lightroom-mobile-ou-snapseed-test-et-comparaison/

From the article:

"The conclusion is without appeal: Lightroom generates much better DNG files than the app from my smartphone. "